# internet works with ip address but not with website name

Tags: networking

I just installed ubuntu on my laptop. I can't ping or open a site with it's name but everything works fine when i use IP address.
I already tested a few ways like disabling ipv6, changing dns server and changing some configuration in firefox.

Comment: change your dns to 8.8.8.8 & then run " sudo service network-manager restart " check if its working

Comment: Is not working, I tried this before

Comment: This has nothing to do with ipv6, unless you actively tried to enable but wasn't successful. This has to do with DNS. What are the contents of /etc/hosts and /etc/resolve.conf? Look and update your question with the contents of those files. And yes,tell us exactly what you have tried. If a test fail, undo any change you done.

Answer (score -1):

it is an error in DNS server settings. DNS is service translating domain names to the IP addresses. Your DNS server is not set properly or does not work properly. Usually this can happen if you set fixed IP address with incorrect DNS. The advice in comment to setup DNS to 8.8.8.8 is correct and can help you, but better will be, if you use your local DNS, usually it is given from your provider or it can be IP address of your local router. For most cases to setup DHCP (automatic IP setup) will work.

Comment: Is not working, I tried this before