# WiFi connection to router but no Internet connection?

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, network-manager

- I installed Ubuntu on my EasyNote-TM86 today.
- I can't access any websites although I am connected to my router.
- Other devices (including my laptop before I installed Ubuntu) are able to establish a connection/load websites.
- Security is WPA/WPA2

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21594/discussion-on-question-by-jakob-wifi-connection-to-router-but-no-internet-connec).

Answer (score 1):

From a search `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` should make `/etc/resolv.conf` but mine only contains `nameserver 127.0.1.1`

Comment: I did this, reconfigured something and restartet but Firefox is still unable to connect.

Comment: Are you using Network Manager or WICD, as Network Manager usually causes the file to be made

Comment: I didn't changed the default settings/programms until now so NetworkManager I think.

Comment: I am starting to think your MAC address might be blocked on the router from other comments as you should be able to ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: Solved the issue with Elementary OS connecting to my router but no to internet - thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to do:

**Restart network manager**

Network manager on my machine is weird. The indicator may show the machine is connected but i cannot ping anything, mostly after startup. What solves it is `sudo service network-manager restart`

**Delete system-connections**

Network manager stores config for every connection in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`  directory. I've noticed that for many users here on askubuntu it has been sufficient to delete every file in that folder and try reconnecting to their network.

**Remove needless stuff from resolv.conf**

```
1    # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) 
2        #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN 

3        nameserver 8.8.8.8 | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv/conf.d/head 
4        printtf nnameserver 
5        nameserver 8.8.8.8 | sudo tee -a /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

This is your resolv.conf file as you posted. Remove lines `sudo tee` from both `/etc/resolv/conf.d/head` and `/etc/resolv.conf.d/base`, as well as the `printf line`

Your base and head files should only contain `nameserver 8.8.8.8` line.

**Try deleting /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf**

`/etc/resolv.conf` file is actually symbolic link to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` file. Delete that actual file, edit `head` and `base` files, reboot.

**Try adding other DNS in nm-connection-editor**

Open nm-connection-editor, either in command line, or under network-indicator drop down menu (Edit Connections). Find your desired network. Select Edit. Under IPv4 settings, select "Automatic (DHCP) Address Only", then add  `208.67.220.220` on the "Additional DNS Servers" line

For more info on the subject, refer to my question and answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/542922/295286). Let me know if this answer was helpful or whether the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

My internet connection got lost after I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. After troubleshooting, I found `/etc/resolv.conf` empty

I also checked the file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail` and found it empty.

I added the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

Everything resolved.