# Cannot access internet from WiFi except my home WiFi!

Tags: networking, wireless

I can't access internet from anywhere except my home!
I can verify that the internet is working, I can connect and browse through my Android.
Also, I can ping 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4!

UPDATE : I can access my website hosted at Vultr with IP! I can even enter my wp-admin!
But I can't SSH to my server ... how weird.
I guess it must be DNS issue ... but why I can connect with my home network if the DNS is wrong?

Comment: Definitely dns issue.  By default network manager grabs dns settings as provided by your router.  I've had similar issue. Refer here : http://askubuntu.com/a/542930/295286

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so Mint is off-topic here as well. However, on http://unix.stackexchange.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  ;-)

Comment: err... I think I should remove the  line which specify it is mint :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to answer it by myself. Sorry :(

EDIT: as mchid suggested, I digged it again, and realized that everytime I run resolvconf -u ...

```
/etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

So I fixed it by linking /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf to /etc/resolv.conf

```
ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Tested using 3 Wireless Network so far, no problem :D

Comment: that's your problem. the nameserver is set to 192.168.1.1 (& .0.1) and public networks probably don't use that.

Comment: well, almost all routers around me use that. do you have any better solution?

Comment: yes, use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 only if you can. Most likely, you don't need to use 192.168.1.1 or 0.1 if you have 8.8.8.8  and 8.8.4.4 set. You could also use opendns instead of google 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.222.220 . oh yeah and by the way, allot of times, you may have to run `resolvconf -u` or `sudo resolvconf -u` to apply those settings.

Comment: these settings are typically automatically set through network-manager but I guess if network-manager isn't doing the job the way it's supposed to, you can always do it this way. Personally, I use dnscrypt and have to set through resolv.conf to get dns pointed in the right direction otherwise it leaks and have found that running `resolvconf -u` gets it to stick after establishing a connection with a public wireless network.

Comment: I edited my answer. It works now.